# Is it possible to scroll a Scroll View layered on top of a UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a child `View Controller` within a `Container View` that hosts a vertically-scrolling `UITableView`. Tapping a `Button` expands a separate `View` that covers the `UITableView` in the child `View Controller`. This new `View` contains a vertically-scrolling `Scroll View`. No matter what `UITableView` settings I change, I am unable to scroll the `Scroll View` unless I remove the `UITableView` entirely.

I am currently porting my fully-developed Android application to IOS, and my experience with Android Studio leads me to believe that this is an issue with the `UITableView` stealing focus from the Scroll View.

In short, how may I temporarily remove focus from the background `UITableView` to allow the overlaid `Scroll View` to scroll?

Answer (score 0):

With `Scroll View`s up until this point, I have been setting the `bottom` -> `Superview` constraint to `priority: 249` since I was having issues setting the `contentSize`. For some reason, having a `Table View` in the background disables this effect. My guess is that this happens because the `Table View` is forcing the `Superview` to anchor based on its own constraints, and therefore the `Scroll View` can no longer adjust based on low-priority constraints. Changing the `Equal Height` parameter of the `Scroll View` -> `Superview` to a proportional relation (x2) has temporarily addressed the problem.